# How do I get all dates starting from JAN 2022, in yyyymm format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date-formatting, date-range

I want to get all dates starting from **JAN 2022**, in *yyyymm* format. This is my code:

```
for(var i = new Date("2022-01"); i < new Date(); i++){
    console.log(i);
}
```

I get the ouptut like this:

```
Sat Jan 01 2022 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
1640995200001
1640995200002...
```

whereas I want the results like:

```
202201
202202
202203....till the current date
```

How do I get the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Let the `Date` builtin handle leap years and different month lengths.

```js
const current = Date.now();
for (const d = new Date("2022-01"); d < current; d.setUTCMonth(d.getUTCMonth() + 1)) {
  console.log(`${d.getUTCFullYear()}${(d.getUTCMonth() + 1 + "").padStart(2, "0")}`);
}
```

An alternative approach is to store year & month separately.

```js
const current = new Date();

for (
  let year = 2022, month = 0;
  year < current.getUTCFullYear() || month <= current.getUTCMonth();
  month = (month + 1) % 12, year += month === 0
) {
  console.log(`${year}${(month + 1 + "").padStart(2, "0")}`);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to handle leap years and different month lengths? The format is YYYYMM? No days.

Comment: @jabaa Because the other way to do it (with Date objects) is to add a certain number of milliseconds to the date, which requires you to take into account leap years and months of different lengths. Yes, you could use two variables `year` and `month` but I prefer answers as similar to the OP's post as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it simple with basic code not using any date

```
let year = 2021;
let month = 12;
while(year < 2030) // choose whatever end date you want
{
    if(month == 12)
    {
        month = 1;
        year++;
    }
    else
        month++;
    console.log(year + month.padStart(2, "0"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toLocaleString` method, the Swedish locale used so that the year is first. `Date.UTC()` is used to make sure that date is consistent in different time-zones :

```js
const startDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2022, 0, 1));
const currentDate = new Date();

for (let d = startDate; d <= currentDate; d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1)) {
  const dateStr = d.toLocaleDateString('sv-SE', { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit' }).replace('-', '');
  console.log(dateStr);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account timezones, on a computer in the Chicago timezone this outputs `["202112", "202201", "202202", "202203", ...]`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I added Date.UTC method and it should be OK now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toISOString()` to get the full date and split it into `yyyymm` format.

```js
function getYYYYMM(d) {
  return i.toISOString().split('T')[0].split('-').join('').slice(0,-2);
}
for(var i = new Date('2022-01'); i <= new Date(); i = new Date(i.setMonth(i.getMonth()+1))) {
  console.log(getYYYYMM(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [generators](https://javascript.info/generators) as well as [`Intl.DateTimeFormat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat):

```js
const current = Date.now();
const startDate = new Date("2022-01");
function* dateRange(startDate, current) {
  for (const d = startDate; d < current; d.setUTCMonth(d.getUTCMonth() + 1)) {
    yield Intl.DateTimeFormat('sv-SE', {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: '2-digit',
        timezone: 'UTC',
    }).format(d).replace('-', '');
  }
}
console.log([...dateRange(startDate, current)])
```

Instead of manipulating the output string, you can make use of `Intl.DateTimeFormat()`'s [`formatToParts()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) method:

```js
const current = Date.now();
const startDate = new Date("2022-01");
function* dateRange(startDate, current) {
  for (const d = startDate; d < current; d.setUTCMonth(d.getUTCMonth() + 1)) {
    yield Intl.DateTimeFormat('sv-SE', {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: '2-digit',
        timezone: 'UTC',
    }).formatToParts(d).filter(p => p.type !== 'literal').map(p => p.value).join('');
  }
}
console.log([...dateRange(startDate, current)])
```

Or you could utilize [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
const current = Date.now();
const today = new Date();
const startDate = new Date("2022-01");
const monthsPerYear = 12;
function dateRange(startDate, current) {
  return Array.from({
      length: today.getFullYear() === startDate.getFullYear()
          ? today.getMonth() - startDate.getMonth()
          : ((monthsPerYear + 1) - today.getMonth()) + (startDate.getMonth() + 2) + ((today.getFullYear() - startDate.getFullYear() - 1) * monthsPerYear)
  }, function(v, i) {
  let date = new Date(startDate);
  date.setUTCMonth(startDate.getUTCMonth() + i)
  return `${date.getFullYear()}${(date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, 0)}`
  });
}
console.log(dateRange(startDate, current))
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account timezones, on a computer in the Chicago timezone this outputs `["202112", "202201", "202202", "202203", ...]`

Comment: I added a fixed timezone